# mysql query to get preview data

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, preview

I have one table in which I have id and parent_id. In admin panel if user click on preview button it redirects to site with preview id. when we click on preview button, data save in table with it's id in 'parent_id' key.

I created query and its working fine but it's displaying data in order but i want to replace parent row with preview row.

```
select * from wp_content
where page='sharepoint_features'
and (status='1' or (status='preview' and parent_id='146'))
and id<>146
```

here 146 is parent id which we got form preview id

by this query we have got following data

[image: enter]

in above table id 1303 should come after 145

Comment: Check the new trial

Answer (score 2):

You must add an `ORDER BY` clause so,

Try this:

```
select * from wp_content
where page='sharepoint_features'
and (status='1'
    or (status='preview' and parent_id='146'))
and id<>146
order by coalesce(CAST(parent_id as INT), id)
```

**UPDATE**

Dear, this is the [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2da3f/1/0), so if I understand your request, the result it's OK.

My result is:

```
144 - a - null
145 - b - null
1303 - c - 146
147 - d - null
```

**UPDATE 2**

Try with this query and tell if it's OK:

```
select * from wp_content
where page='sharepoint_features'
and (status='1'
    or (status='preview' and parent_id='146'))
and id<>146
order by 
case 
    when parent_id is null then id
    else CONVERT(cast parent_id as INT)
end
```

Comment: getting same result joe

Comment: parent_id column is varchar type so i have used order by coalesce(cast(`parent_id` as INT),id) but still getting same

Comment: @vishal:Dear, have you seen my sql fiddle? Is it ok?

Comment: yes its working fine, its mysql version problem. I have mysql 5.0.12. do you have any work around for this version?

Comment: Dear, Mysql 5.0.12 is an old old old version (2005) maybe there were issues about ORDER BY

Comment: thanks joe, got your point but any alternative of this issue? except mysql updaition.

Comment: @vishal: The new query doesn't work on your MySql instance?

Comment: yes update 2 is also not working. getting error in case

Comment: @vishal: Sorry but I haven't got a MySql 5.0.12 instance installed, so I can try the correct query for that version. I advice to upgrade, if possible, your db server

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible work around based on @JoeTaras solution:

```
select * from wp_content
where page='sharepoint_features'
and (status='1'
    or (status='preview' and parent_id='146'))
and id<>146
order by coalesce(NULLIF(parent_id, ''), id)
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4795c2/3) with what I assume is your data structure.

Comment: thanks @CUGreen but its not working. parent_id is varchar, so field would be null or empty.

Comment: @vishal, again, did you check the link to the sql fiddle I updated? It has parent_id as varchar. Shall we just assume then that it is your version of mysql causing issues here?

Comment: yes i have mysql version 5.0.12. Version is issue. But i want to run that query on my version